# implement zoom in zoom out and drag able JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I implemented the zoom in and zoom out with jQuery, and the problem is that the user can drag the image in div and thus creating a space between the image and div
I want the corners of the image to not be inside the div but to be able to go outside the div
I want to implement something like [this](https://0.s3.envato.com/files/78471334/index.html)
and this is [my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmGxN.png)

i used [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Panning-Zooming-Any-Elements-panzoom.html#:%7E:text=panzoom%20is%20a%20simple%20jQuery,and%20many%20other%20html%20elements.) plugin for zoomin zoomout

my html code:

```
 <div style="background-color: white; border : 1px solid #d6d6d6ee; margin: 1rem; width: fit-content;">
      <div class="zoom--actions" style="margin: 5px;">
          <a id="zoom-in"><img style="width: 25px; cursor: pointer;" src="zoomIn.png" /></a>
        <a id="zoom-out"><img style="width: 25px; cursor: pointer;" src="zoomOut.png" /></a>
        <a id="reset"><img style="width: 25px; cursor: pointer;" src="reset.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div id="zoom-box" class="parent" style="background-color: antiquewhite; overflow: hidden;">
          <div class="panzoom" id="panzoom-element">
              <img id="main-image" class="product-main-image mb-3" src="images/1.jpg">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

default options:

```
 var defaultOptions = {
        animate: false,
        canvas: false,
        cursor: 'move',
        disablePan: false,
        disableZoom: false,
        disableXAxis: false,
        disableYAxis: false,
        duration: 200,
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        exclude: [],
        excludeClass: 'panzoom-exclude',
        handleStartEvent: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        maxScale: 4,
        minScale: 1,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        panOnlyWhenZoomed: false,
        relative: false,
        setTransform: setTransform,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        startScale: 1,
        step: 0.5,
        touchAction: 'none'
    };
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `mb-3` on the image. This is probably what is adding your white space on the image. You should add the `mb-3` to the container of the image rather than on the image itself.

**EDIT:** You could try;

```
 var defaultOptions = {
        animate: false,
        canvas: false,
        cursor: 'move',
        contain: 'outside',
        disablePan: false,
        disableZoom: false,
        disableXAxis: false,
        disableYAxis: false,
        duration: 200,
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        exclude: [],
        excludeClass: 'panzoom-exclude',
        handleStartEvent: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        maxScale: 4,
        minScale: 1,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        panOnlyWhenZoomed: false,
        relative: false,
        setTransform: setTransform,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        startScale: 1,
        step: 0.5,
        touchAction: 'none'
    };
```

Comment: thanks for your response
but my problem is that the user can drag the image into the div

Comment: Check the documentation - change the setting ``contain`` to be ``inside``.
By default, ``contain`` is set to ``null`` on the script. This will prevent the image from being dragged outside the container.

Comment: Also ensure you have ``overflow`` set to ``hidden``. It's not the best little plugin you're using, so experiment a bit with the options or find another little plugin :)

Comment: thanks Dexterians, overflow is set to hidden, and in script file It is not possible to change the contain value
i updated my post and added defaultOptions

Comment: You add the option yourself. Ie ``contain: 'inside',``

Comment: I added contain: 'inside' in default options but the zoom and drag feature failed

Comment: Look at my edit, should show you.
If you added it at the end, you need to ensure you have a comma that separates the options - and the last option can't end in a comma.

Comment: Are you able to put it together in a JSFiddle or CodePen and I'll take a peek for you? But again - I'm not so sure how well this plugin of yours handles dragging the image out of bounds. It doesn't seem to handle that very well and I'm having to click 'RESET' to re-center my image.

Comment: it worked whith contain: 'outside',
thanks very much  Dexterians

Comment: I was just about to say, try with 'outside' as I was able to get it to work that way. Strange. Looks like inside/outside work oppositely :P